# Construction of a isoceles Triangle

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

How can one construct an isosceles triangle with ruler and compass with the following givens

1. the sum of the base and a side
2. the head angle

Comment: Hint:  construct some isosceles triangle with the given angle.  Construct the scale factor for your triangle and the desired one, scale your triangle accordingly.

Comment: What are the values given?

Comment: There are infinitely many isosceles triangle with given sum of base and side.

Comment: But there is also the head angle. In other words all the angles are given/

Comment: This is not possible without using trig.

Comment: @simplest_mathematics:  You can do it without trig, per Comments posted on your Answer below.

Comment: @hardmath, whatever happens, you require sin cos tan cot etc. trig aren't they?

Comment: I found myself a very simple answer to this question.  As stated in the question an isosceles triangle is required so that if we have the head angle we know all the angles. if the head angle is θ the base angles are 90-θ/2 .

Answer (score 2):

As more than one comment has pointed out, your triangle is fully determined by your givens.

Let your base be $b$ and the other equal sides each be $a$. The vertex ("head") angle is $\theta$.

The base angles are each $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}2 - \frac 12 \theta$.

By the Sine Rule,

$$\frac a{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac 12 \theta)} = \frac b{\sin\theta}$$

$$2a\sin\frac 12 \theta \cos \frac 12 \theta = b\cos \frac 12 \theta$$

The cosine terms can be cancelled if we disregard the degenerate case of $\theta = \pi$, so

$$b = 2a \sin\frac 12 \theta$$

Now you're given the sum of $a$ and $b$, let's call that $s$. So $b = s - a$.

Solving for $a$, we get:

$$a = \frac s{1 + 2\sin\frac 12 \theta}$$

which will immediately allow you to construct the required triangle with a ruler and protractor.

Comment: Very amateur comment, but is that in radians? If so, perfect! One in radians, and another in degrees! (Doesn't make a difference really...) Too enthusiastic, as my tutor says...

Comment: @simplest_mathematics:  I think the spirit of the Question is that the "head angle" is simply given as an angle, without measurement of either kind.  An angle can be bisected with ruler and compass, and the rest of the construction is to be carried out in a geometric way.

Comment: I would like to give an answer to the question I posted but I am new to his site and I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Split your isosceles triangle in half. You now have a right angled triangle ($c$ is the hypotenuse). Call the head angle $\theta$ The head angle has been halved, so replace $\theta$ with $\frac{\theta}{2}$. Then, subtract $\theta$ from 90 to get the angle opposite the head angle, but not the right angle. Call the other sides $b$ and $a$, with $b$ being the base. $b + c = x$ . $c = x-b$ _______ $a^2 + b^2 = (x-b)^2$ _______________ $a^2 + b^2 = x^2 +b^2 - 2bx, a^2 = x^2 - 2bx$.

Sine rule : $$\frac{b}{\sin {\frac{\theta}{2}}}=\frac{x-b}{\sin (90-{\frac{\theta}{2})}}$$ because $c = x-b$
$$\frac{x-b}{\sin (90-{\frac{\theta}{2})}}=\frac{x-b}{\cos \frac{\theta}{2}}$$

Because of the trig identity $sin(90-x)\equiv cos(x)$

$$\frac{x-b}{\cos \frac{\theta}{2}}=\frac{b}{\sin {\frac{\theta}{2}}}$$

By multiplying by $\cos(\theta/2)$ and dividing by $b$,

$$\frac{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}{\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}} = \frac{x-b}{b} = \cot{\frac{\theta}{2}} $$

because of the identity $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \equiv \cot x$

$$\frac{x-b}{b} = \cot{\frac{\theta}{2}} $$

If we expand the LHS, we get $\frac{x}{b} +\frac{-b}{b} = \frac{x}{b} - 1$

Now, if we add $1$, we get:

$$\frac{x}{b} = \cot (\frac{\theta}{2}) +1$$

Take the reciprocal, and we get:

$$\frac{b}{x} = \frac{1}{\cot(\frac{\theta}{2})+1}$$

And finally, multiply be $x$

$$b = \frac{x}{\cot(\frac{\theta}{2})+1}$$

With this, you can find other side lengths, to make it suitable to construct!

Comment: The answer should be using only geometry . (Not trig functions)

Comment: Other than terminology this doesn't use any trig knowledge.  The sine rule is just another way of saying given two similar triangles abc and a'b'c' then a/a' = b'/b = c'/c.  If the isoceles triangle has sides s, and base b, and altitude h (which is $s\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$) then sin theta/2 is just a way of writing b/2s.  and cos theta/2 of writing h/s.  and cot theta/2 of writing h/(b/2).  Using that notation everything here is just geometry; no trig.

Comment: @fleablood , do I have to edit anything? If I do, please edit it yourself. Let me take this chance to apologise for the misunderstandings of my previous post

Comment: You've made some progress toward solving the problem *without* trigonometry.  Retrace your steps after constructing the initial right triangle and think *similarity*.

Comment: @hardmath , would this be correct otherwise?

Comment: I think if you work out a ruler and compass approach, it will be much simpler.

Comment: @hardmath, I presume it is correct

Comment: Hmm, my comment several hours ago didn't post.  I don't think you need to or should change anything, my comment was to Philippe that although this answer uses trigonometry *terminology* it doesn't use any *concepts* that are not simple geometry.  If one is aware of what the terminology means (which I spelled out) there is nothing that a geometry student couldn't follow.

Comment: @fleablod I am not a dictionary. I have to use a dictionary to know what hard words mean.

Answer (score 0):

Given the length of AP (= AY + YP as a whole) and $\angle A$. The object is to locate X (and therefore Y) such that $\triangle AXY$ is isosceles.

[image]

1. Construct AA’ = the angle bisector of $\angle A$.
2. Form the rhombus APA’P’.
3. Let the angle bisector of $\angle APP’$ cut AP’ at X. Then, $\angle 1 = \angle 2$

Proof: XY should be a line parallel to PP’. Then, $\angle 1 = \angle 3$.

$\angle 3 = \angle 2$ implies XY = YP.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the angle $\theta$

Let's call the sides length $a$ and the base length $b$.  For convenience let's say that $a+b=1$ unit.  (Doesn't matter what unit so we just *define* $1 = a+ b$)

With $\theta$ we can construct arbitrary similar isosceles triangles of arbitrary size.  We can construct one where the side is $1$.  This triangle has a scale of $1/a$ compared to the triangle we want. ($1 = a*\frac 1a$).  So the base is $b*\frac 1a = \frac ba$ in length.

We can construct the base angles, so we can construct a base of length $1$ and the two base angles to construct a similar isosceles triangle with base $=1$.  This triangle will have a scale of $1/b$.  ($1 = b*\frac 1b$).  So the sides of this triangle is $a*\frac 1b = \frac ab$ in length.

So we can construct lengths of $1$, $a/b$ and $b/c$ and we need to figure out how to construct a length of $a$ or $b$ from these.

Now $a = \frac a1 = \frac a{a+b} = \frac 1{1 + b/a}$.

Constructing a segment of length $1 + b/a$ is simple extension.

If we have a length $m$ and length $1$ we can construct length $1/m$ like this:

Make a segment of $\overline {AB}$ of length $m$.  Make a perpendicular line at $B$.  Mark off point $C$ at a distance of $1$.  So $ABC$ is a right triangle. $AB = m$ and $BC=1$.  Construct an perpendicular to $\overline {BC}$ at $C$.  Extend it until it intersects $\vec{AB}$ at point $D$.

Triangles $ABC$ and $CBD$ are similar.  And $\frac {AB}{BC} = \frac {BC}{BD}$ and so $BD = BC*\frac {BC}{AB} = 1*\frac 1m = \frac 1m$.

So lets put this all together:

1) Construct $\angle \theta$ at point $O$ and mark off $A$ and $B$  so that $OA = OB= a+b$ and $\angle AOB = \theta$.  This is an isosceles triangle proportional to the one we want.

$AB = m = \frac {b(a+b)}a$.

1) Construct $\angle \theta$ at point $O$ and mark off $A$ and $B$ at any distance so that $OA = OB$ and $\angle AOB = \theta$.  This is an isosceles triangle proportional to the one we want.

2) Elsewhere construct a line $\overline {CD}$ of length $m = AB$.  Extend it to $CE$ so that $CD = CD + a+b = m + a+ b= (a+b)(1 + \frac ba)$.

3) Elsewhere construct a right triangle $FGH$ so that $FG = CE = (a+b)(1 + \frac ba)$ and $GH= a+b$.

4) Construct triangle $HGI$ so that $\angle FHI$ is right, and $I$ is the point of intersection with $\vec {FG}$.

$\triangle FGH$ is similar to $\triangle HGI$ and $\frac {GI}{HG}= \frac {HG}{FG}$ and $GI = HG^2\frac 1{FG} = (a+b)^2\frac  {1}{(a+b)(1 + \frac ba)}=\frac{a+b}{1 + \frac ba}= a$

5) Elsewhere construct triangle $JKL$ so that $JK = GI = a$ and $\angle JKL = \theta$ and $KL = GI = a$.